# PHP weird behavior when rounding (number gets really big)

Tags: php, rounding

When I run this:

```
<?php echo round(8.553577896, 2); ?>
```

It returns `8.550000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125` instead of `8.55`. Why? Is there any way I can make it work correctly using the `round` function?

I'm using PHP 5.4.4 in Windows NT 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Ultimate Edition Service Pack 1)

Comment: It's working for me. See http://ideone.com/DAI7zX

Comment: Must be Winblows... returning 8.55 form me via a linux box.

Comment: it's giving exact answer 8.55 .

Comment: I am not sure what is problem but, you can alternatively use **number_format()**. Like : **number_format(8.553577896, 2);**

Comment: It's not last stable version of PHP.

Comment: Lools like a [float](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) problem, but strange. Works fine for me too. And yes, as @safarov said, you can use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for those puropses.

Comment: @safarov That, worked. I don't know why round doesn't. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: .55 doesn't have an exact representation in binary floating point. It looks like Windows is using a floating point representation with more precision than Unix, so the difference shows up there.

Comment: No problems with PHP 5.3.8 on Windoze

Comment: (i) what microprocessor do you have (ii) what result does `<?php echo 8.55; ?>` produce?

Comment: 1 -I'm using  Intel Core 2 Duo

2-'<?php echo 8.55; ?>' echoes '8.550000000000000710542735760100185871124' I hadn´t noticed that... I'm using xampp, i'l update php to 5.4.7 and then try again.

Comment: Updated to PHP 5.4.7. The same. Thank you all for your help :D

Comment: submit a php bug. php.net/bugs

Answer (score -5):

Is there a `round()` function in PHP?

```
<?php
    print round(8.553577896, 2);
?>
```

Try that, im not fully sure tho.